# How to force insert a duplicate key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

It's a daily struggle to work with the previous programmer his code... And now, apparently, also his database.

#### Problem description

So here we've got a table to store the availability of a user and normally you would assign a unique id to every row of data. Except... he didn't. He made the user_id the first primary key (probably a composite).
So the user changes his availability for each weekday (monday to friday) and every timeslot in that week. 
This is made into one row each:

```
user_id,day,hour_nr,hour_type,location_id
```

But you might see this one coming, I can't manually insert fake data for developing purposes. I'm trying to add a period and college year (it's for an educational institution) Which worked fine but because the old data didn't require this it's all set to 0.

The new row will consist of:

```
user_id,day,hour_nr,hour_type,location_id,period_id,collegeyear_id
```

I've tried uploading data to the table containing the period and college year information but I get an instant error telling me that there is a duplicate entry.
That's correct there is but there already were duplicates as well.

#### Question

And so the question is: how do I force this without altering the tables keys? I don't feel much for altering the indexed properties of the composite primary key.

Lastly, I know this is wrong and I know that it should have been done differently. Again it's not my work or design and I don't have any time on hand to fix or alter it during this project.

#### Edit

As requested, hereby a snapshot of the table with data and a snapshot of how it should be

The snapshot shows different headers than mentioned, they're the same but in Dutch.

[Current data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ7Ve.png) (I forgot to put the last 2 columns that are in the Desired data result snapshot on the snapshot but they're already there containing nothing but 0's)

[Desired data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpQ0v.png)

I do need an`INSERT`, the data has to be added not altered. Or another fix for this issue ofcourse but the data has to be added.

#### Fix

So in a perfect example of tunnel vision I fixed and therefore answered my own question.

Instead of looking blindly at inserting the data I should have looked more towards the composite key part. I've added the 2 new columns to the key and now all is fine and dandy.

I said that I didn't want to mess with the keys but that was pointed towards the already existing keys not adding to the composite key.

I still dislike the fact that there isn't a single unique id but it is workable.

Comment: You can't "force a duplicate key".  It's a key, it doesn't allow duplicates.  Do you mean that you want to `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` when a key exists?

Comment: Could you provide us more information, like the current table with examples and the desired result. This will help a lot. Also the insert queries

Comment: I'll edit the post, I did not mean `UPDATE`. It has to be added not changed.

Comment: Looking at the data snapshots, it appears as though the composite key is based across all the columns. You may need to update the key to take into account the period and college year. Do you have a table schema we can look at?

Comment: The whole point of a key  is to provide at least one truly unique piece of information for a given row, where all other pieces of information in all other rows can remain complete clones of each other. You don't NEED a key, but if you chose not to, there is no way to guarantee that each row will have something to differentiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in a perfect example of tunnel vision I fixed and therefore answered my own question.

Instead of looking blindly at inserting the data I should have looked more towards the composite key part. I've added the 2 new columns to the key and now all is fine and dandy.

I said that I didn't want to mess with the keys but that was pointed towards the already existing keys not adding to the composite key.

I still dislike the fact that there isn't a single unique id but it is workable.

Comment: Update your question

Answer (score 0):

Q.
And so the question is: how do I force this without altering the tables keys? I don't feel much for altering the indexed properties of the composite primary key.

A.
You cannot force the primary key to have multiple values of the same ID.
The best thing for you to do would be to add an extra column with a new ID and reference that within the software.

A primary key is a special relational database table column (or combination of columns) designated to uniquely identify all table records.

A primary key’s main features are:

It must contain a unique value for each row of data.
It cannot contain null values.
A primary key is either an existing table column or a column that is specifically generated by the database according to a defined sequence.

Resources:- [techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5547/primary-key)

Comment: I know that I can't force a duplicate key (might have been a worng choice of words) but looking at the data that is in it has been done.

Figured it out! Added them to the composite key

Comment: Can you provide a data schema?